# ProGuard can't find referenced class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient

Tags: android, proguard

When I export a signed apk, the following error is shown:

```
Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaj: can't find referenced method 'void addHeader(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)' in program class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzak
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzak: can't find referenced method 'void setURI(java.net.URI)' in program class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzak
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzar: can't find referenced class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient
```

Is it safe to just add these `Proguard` rules:

```
-keep class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient
-dontwarn android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient
```

Or do I also have to include `org.apache.http.legacy.jar` in the project?

Answer (score -1):

Add this line to your proguard. It will not affect anything in your code

```
-dontwarn org.apache.http.**
```